# SVN problems re-integrating branch

Tags: svn

I'm trying to re-integrate a branch in SVN.  When I run this:

```
~/branch$ svn merge ^/trunk .
```

everything is clean.  The branch has all `^/trunk` revisions merged in ok.  However, when I try to merge the branch back into the trunk, I get:

```
~/trunk$ svn merge ^/branches/std2_1dev .
svn: E195016: Reintegrate can only be used if revisions 15985 through 16741 were previously merged from https://xxx/svn/repo/trunk to the reintegrate source, but this is not the case:
  branches/std2_1dev/00_common/etc/qtg
    Missing ranges: /trunk/00_common/etc/qtg:16700-16701
```

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127281/subversive-svn-e195016-cannot-merge-into-a-working-copy-with-a-switched-subtr) that suggested this problem is related to `svn sw`, but `~/trunk` is a fresh `svn checkout`.

When I look at the actual commit contents:

- 16700 contains a change to `^/trunk/00_common/etc/qtg`'s property `svn:mergeinfo`.
- 16701 performs a reverse merge of 16700 with `svn merge -r 16700:16699 .` undoing 16700.
- `svn diff -r 16699:16701` returns nothing (so the reverse merge seems to have worked).

How can I recover and perform the re-integration of my branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `svn:mergeinfo` on the root suggested that the revisions were merged:

```
~/src/branch$ svn propget svn:mergeinfo . | grep trunk
/trunk:15985-16741
```

But the problem still existed.

The solution was to explicitly merge in these revisions and commit:

```
~/src/branch$ svn merge -r 16699:16701 .
~/src/branch$ svn ci
```

Then the re-integration worked great:

```
~/src/trunk$ svn merge ^/branch/std2_1dev .
```